# jQuery ajax scope memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, closures

I wonder whether memory leak can occur in the following pseudo jQuery code (because the success callback always have a reference to _this)?

```
var _this = this;

$.ajax({
  url: "foo",
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  success: function() {
      // Do stuff with _this
      _this.doStuffs();
})
```

Comment: That's because you declared `_this` in a higher scope, and the variable is still accessible ?

Comment: _this will always be available. That's why I wonder whether this pattern can lead to any memory leak? I think it might since the 'success' callback will always have a reference to _this (hence the garbage collection won't pick it up)

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but when declaring a variable it will be available in functions within that scope or lower, there's nothing magically different in that success function, the _this variable is accessible because it's declared in a higher scope, just like it would be in any other function, and that's the way javascript is usually written.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code within a function ?

If yes (which I guess), _this will be illegible to garbage-collection right after the ajax call has completed or failed. So there is no reason in theory to worry about memory leak here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a memory leak there. The success callback should be garbage collected after being called (has to be implemented correctly, you've got that right - but it *is* done properly by jQuery and browsers, maybe even in IE). After that, also the `_this` object could be collected (if not referenced from outside) - but not before of course, that's the purpose of the closure.